# Mapping lidar data in Husky A200

Tags: navigation, a200, husky, hokuyo, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello Guys,

```
      I am currently working on **Husky A200**. I am finding difficulties in mapping the **lidar data** obtained from Husky A200, in order to map the environment.I am using **Hokuyo Lidar** and Ubuntu 11.10(Oneric Ocelot).Any help would be highly appreciated.
```

Thanks in Advance

> Blockquote

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32456/mapping-lidar-data-in-husky-a200/) by [Arjun PE](https://answers.ros.org/users/2019/arjun-pe/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2012-04-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey Arjun,

If you're just trying to visualize the laser data, the [hokuyo_node](http://ros.org/wiki/hokuyo_node) package comes with a great launch file that sets up the driver and an rviz instance. See the package page for more info.

If you're wanting to run all of [gmapping](http://www.ros.org/wiki/gmapping), your best bet might actually be to hold tight! We just got it set up with the Husky and a Kinect recently, and will be releasing those launch files in the next week or so. If you ping us at support@clearpathrobotics.com, we'll be sure to let you know right away when it's up, and we can help you adapt it for use with the Hokuyo.

Mike

---

Originally posted by [mikepurvis](https://answers.ros.org/users/270/mikepurvis/) with karma: 1153 on 2012-04-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

We've updated the [Husky wiki page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Robots/Husky) with launchfiles that both us and a number of our clients are using. Please let us know your feedback and we'll try to incorporate it!

---

Originally posted by [Ryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/195/ryan/) with karma: 3248 on 2012-09-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1